# im trying to run a url file for my website, but it i keep getting an error in powershell

Tags: python, django

the file im working in is called C:\users\Kalen\Desktop\django 1\mysite\blog\urls.py and the code inside the file is

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import Post

urlpatterns =  [url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date"[:25]),
                                            template_name=("blog/blog.html"))]
```

when I go into my PowerShell and run python manage.py runserver I get an error saying the ] at the end of template_name is invalid syntax. so I remove it and then I get an error that says unexpected EOF while parsing. I looked up what the error means but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your syntax is wrong, missed one closing parenthesis,
Try below,

```
[url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date"[:25]),
                                            template_name=("blog/blog.html")))]
```